# how to calculate jaccard similarity on dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to find similar users using jaccard similarity.

I want to change original df like result df.

The result df column value is the intersection/union.

for example..

The similarity between User 1 and User 2 is 1/2.

1/2 = The number of items both users have in common/
Total number of items both users have

In this way, I want to create an result df that calculates the similarity of all users.

What should I do?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a function which calculates number of items both user have in common divide by the total number of items.

```
calc <- function(x, y) {
  sum(x == 'Y' & y == 'Y')/sum(x == 'Y' | y == 'Y')  
}
```

Split the data rowwise and use `outer` :

```
tmp <- asplit(df, 1)
outer(tmp, tmp, Vectorize(calc))

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4] [,5]
#[1,] 1.000  0.5  0.0 0.333  0.4
#[2,] 0.500  1.0  0.0 0.000  0.2
#[3,] 0.000  0.0  1.0 0.000  0.4
#[4,] 0.333  0.0  0.0 1.000  0.4
#[5,] 0.400  0.2  0.4 0.400  1.0
```

**data**

It would be helpful if you provide data in a reproducible format instead of an image.

```
df <- data.frame(item1 = c('Y', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y'), 
                 item2 = c('Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'Y'), 
                 item3 = c('N', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y'), 
                 item4 = c('N', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y'), 
                 item5 = c('N', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'Y'))
```

Comment: Thanks!
However, looking at the results, it is impossible to know which user it is. 
Can the user ID be the column name?

Comment: Yes, if the user id is stored in rownames of `df`, store the output in `result <- outer(tmp, tmp, Vectorize(calc))` and then you can do `dimnames(result) <- list(rownames(df), rownames(df))`. This will change both column and rowname of the output. If you want to change only the column name use `colnames(result) <- rownames(df)`.

Comment: Thank you so much!
After executing the `rownames(df) <- df[,1]` command, I did what you told me, and got the desired result! Now both row and column names have been changed to user IDs.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? 
I want to extract similar users with similarity of 0.5 for each user and put those values ​​as an array in the last column of result df. Are there any commands that can be solved at once?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Can you ask that as a new question with sample input and expected output? Thanks.

Comment: please check this question! thanks!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66649428/how-to-extract-column-names-for-each-row-using-column-values-inr

Comment: That's the last question.
Is there a way to use less memory than the method you answered in the first place?
There are too many users, causing memory issues...

Comment: Yes, `outer` can be memory consuming and slow. Unfortunately , I don't know other alternative method which can do the same. Would it work if you divide the data into chunks and repeat the process on smaller chunks of data ?

Comment: It is executed by breaking the data into smaller units.
However, if the data is divided into periods or other conditions and executed, the similarity may be calculated incorrectly, So I am a little careful using this method...